# Swift: Change Container height and origin from another class

Tags: swift, containers

I have a main view controller and in that controller I have two containers. I want to change the origin point of the top container by pressing the button from the bottom view controller. A simple top drawer. As you can guess i am a beginner.

I just could not reference the top container to my bottomViewController class.

Thanks
Koray Birand

Comment: Solved it by delegating self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare a variable pointing out your class above it.
and in that class add a function which changes the iboulet of the related constraints constant to a desired value.

```
var mV = MainViewController()
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var topAlign: NSLayoutConstraint!

      func moveTop () {
          topAlign.constant = 100
      }

}
```

and then in the other class just call the fuction:

```
mV.moveTop()
```